# Заполнить чарт Lavacharts в цикле

Tags: laravel, диаграммы

Всем привет,
  Делаю чарты используя Lavacharts ( laravel 5.5 ).
  И такой коди из примеров работает :

```
    $reasons = $lava->DataTable();

    $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')
            ->addNumberColumn('Percent')
            ->addRow(array('Check Reviews', 5))
            ->addRow(array('Watch Trailers', 2))
            ->addRow(array('See Actors Other Work', 4))
            ->addRow(array('Settle Argument', 89));

    $donutchart = $lava->DonutChart('IMDB', $reasons, [
        'title' => 'Reasons I visit IMDB'
    ]);
```

Но у меня массив данных в виде:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => PC Gaming
            [category_slug] => pc-gaming
            [category_id] => 3
            [sold_sum] => 25.75
            [qty_sum] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_name] => Singles
            [category_slug] => singles
            [category_id] => 5
            [sold_sum] => 7.29
            [qty_sum] => 3
        )
```

Пытаюсь заполнить в массиве :

```
    $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')
            ->addNumberColumn("Sold ".$currency_currency_short);
    foreach( $reportDataList as $nextReportRow ) {
        $reasons->addRow(  array( $nextReportRow['category_name'], $nextReportRow['sold_sum'] )  );
    }

    $donutchart = $lava->DonutChart('IMDB', $reasons, [
        'title' => 'Reasons I visit IMDB'
    ]);
```

и чарт не отображается - в консоле ошибок нет.

А как правильно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду используется метод `chaining`, как на русском языке он называется не припомню, но суть в том что он возвращает сам себя, то есть нужно каждое обращение в вашем случае возвращать в переменную, выглядит это вот так:

```
$reasons = $lava->DataTable();

$reasons = $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')
                   ->addNumberColumn("Sold ".$currency_currency_short);

foreach( $reportDataList as $nextReportRow ) {
    $reasons = $reasons->addRow(  array( $nextReportRow['category_name'], $nextReportRow['sold_sum'] )  );
}

$donutchart = $lava->DonutChart('IMDB', $reasons, [
    'title' => 'Reasons I visit IMDB'
]);
```

Так должно отработать всё если данные валидны.

Comment: Увы, не помогло...

Comment: @mstdmstd Попробуйте в стиле моего ответа сделать код из примера, если заработает - значит данные не правильно отдаете.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, помогло если сумму привести к флоату:

```
 (float)$nextReportRow['sold_sum']
```

но:
 1) я перед суммой поставил сумму валюты $ и в результате вещественные суммы стали отображаться без целой части, то есть “25.75”=>".75" ?
 Это какие-то настройки чарта?

2) А как можно задать размеры на разных устройствах, поскольку ширина задается на стороне php :

```
 $donutchart = $lava->DonutChart('report_orders_sum_by_categories', $reasons, [
    'title' => 'Sold sums by categories',
    'width'             => 800,
    'height'             => 800,
]);
```

?